# How to handle change orientation events correctly?

Tags: xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin.Android.

When I change orientation, my app is reopening. How can I stop this bug? (I don't want to lock orientation changing.)

Comment: Can you post your code / give us a little bit more to work with? Is there an error when this occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent activity restart, add the following code for your Activity:

```
[Activity (Label = "CodeLayoutActivity", ConfigurationChanges=Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]
```

You can refer to more details in xamarin documentation [HERE](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/handling_rotation/#Preventing_Activity_Restart).